# Combined class and interface type

Tags: typescript, activexobject

In Javascript (under WScript or HTA), I would write the following pattern:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var ext = fso.GetExtensionName('C:\test.txt');    //returns 'txt'
var badResult = fso.NonExistentMethod();          //raises a runtime error
```

Using TypeScript, I can declare an interface which will prevent this sort of error:

```
module Scripting {
    export interface FileSystemObject {
        GetExtensionName(path: string): string,
        GetParentFolderName(path: string): string
    }
}

var fso: Scripting.FileSystemObject = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var ext = fso.GetExtensionName('C:\test.txt'); //ext is recognized as a string
//var badResult = fso.NonExistentMethod();     //will not compile
```

However, I would like to initialize the `fso` variable like this:

```
var fso = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
```

and have the type system automatically deduce that the type of `fso` is the interface `Scripting.FileSystemObject`.

Can this be done?

---

1) I can't add the constructor to the interface, because the interface is only the shape of the object, not its implementation.

---

2) I thought about creating an internal interface, and extending the interface with a class and a constructor:

```
module Scripting {
    interface Internal {
        GetExtensionName(path: string): string;
        GetParentFolderName(path: string): string;
    }

    export class FileSystemObject extends Internal {
        constructor() {
            return new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
        }
    }
}
```

but constructors cannot be added to an extending class without a call to the base type constructor, which an interface does not have.

---

3) I cannot have a single `declared` class, because the constructor is still an implementation and cannot be written into a `declared` class, which is an ambient context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> deduce that the type of fso is the interface Scripting.FileSystemObject.Can this be done?

Sure. Just declare to have something which when called with `new` will return the correct type. i.e. `export var FileSystemObject: { new (): FileSystemObject };` below :

```
declare module Scripting {
    export interface FileSystemObject {
        GetExtensionName(path: string): string;
        GetParentFolderName(path: string): string;
    }
    export var FileSystemObject: { new (): FileSystemObject };
}

var fso: Scripting.FileSystemObject = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
var ext = fso.GetExtensionName('C:\test.txt'); //ext is recognized as a string
var badResult = fso.NonExistentMethod();     //will not compile
```

[try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20module%20Scripting%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20FileSystemObject%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GetExtensionName(path%3A%20string)%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GetParentFolderName(path%3A%20string)%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09export%20var%20FileSystemObject%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20FileSystemObject%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20fso%3A%20Scripting.FileSystemObject%20%3D%20new%20Scripting.FileSystemObject()%3B%0Avar%20ext%20%3D%20fso.GetExtensionName('C%3A%5Ctest.txt')%3B%20%2F%2Fext%20is%20recognized%20as%20a%20string%0Avar%20badResult%20%3D%20fso.NonExistentMethod()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fwill%20not%20compile)

**UPDATE** To implement something like this yourself you can do:

```
module Scripting {
    export interface FileSystemObject {
        GetExtensionName(path: string): string;
        GetParentFolderName(path: string): string;
    }
    export var FileSystemObject: { new (): FileSystemObject } = <any>function(){
        return new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    };
}

var fso: Scripting.FileSystemObject = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
var ext = fso.GetExtensionName('C:\test.txt'); //ext is recognized as a string
var badResult = fso.NonExistentMethod();     //will not compile
```

Comment: And actually I don't need the type annotation on `fso`. However, I'm still confused. Where do I put the constructor implementation that `new Scripting.FileSystemObject()` runs `new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystem');`?

Comment: I thought you `new Scripting.FileSystemObject();` was ambient i.e. declared in javascript elsewhere. If you want to create it in TypeScript see my update